# Devise error messasge do not shows proper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Fresh install Rails 7 and and devise 4.8.1

If I login in with wrong password, a flash error message will show up to page, like following screenshot:

[image]

But the weird thing is that flash error message is append to the end of html, like following screenshot:

[image]

the `_error_message.html.erb` is located in `app/views/deivse/shared`:

```
<% if resource.errors.any? %>
<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>
      <%= I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                 count: resource.errors.count,
                 resource: resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)
       %>
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I try to change above error view file, but the flash message still not change, even I empty the error view file.

Comment: sure that **app/views/deivse/shared** is the filepath?

Comment: The partial _error_message is not the same thing as a flash. You rather have to check how your flashes are rendered.

Comment: yeah, probably they are rendered below the body?

Comment: I have the same issue! have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Look into app/views/devise folder.

Adapt Devise to Rails 7: Devise is not yet fully compatible with Rails 7.

We need to disable Turbo on Devise forms:

```
<!-- app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb -->
<!-- [...] -->
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), data: {turbo: false}) do |f| %>

<!-- app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb -->
<!-- [...] -->
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), data: {turbo: false}) do |f| %>
```

All you need is to insert: data: {turbo: false}.